# Laravel 5.2 - Login is not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I have simple registration code:

```
$data = [
     'email' => $post['email'],
     'password' => Crypt::encrypt($post['password']),
];
$user = User::create($data);
$mailer->sendEmailConfirmationTo($user);
```

This is my `routes.php`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'auth'], function(){
        Route::get('/', 'AuthController@index');
        Route::post('post', 'AuthController@postLogin');

        Route::group(['prefix'=>'register'], function() {
            Route::get('/', 'AuthController@register');
            Route::post('post', 'AuthController@postRegister');
            Route::get('confirm/{email}/{confirmation_key}', 'AuthController@confirm');
        });
    });
});
```

And this is my login code:

```
$post = $request->all();

if (\Auth::attempt(['email' => $post['email'], 'password' => Crypt::encrypt($post['password'])]))
    return 'loginSuccess';
return 'loginFailed';
```

It always return `loginFailed`, never return `loginSuccess`.
What can i do?

Comment: The documentation for Auth::attempt says to use the password as the argument, not the crypted/hashed password....

Comment: Also, why are you using Crypt to create passwords that can be decrypted, rather than Hash?

Comment: as Mark Baker is pointing out, the plain text password gets passed to the attempt method, as it needs to compare the hash of it to what is in the database. The passwords are hashed, not encrypted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is example should working.

1. Create user's password using Hash::make() function when you create user data

   Hash::make('password');
2. Login using code below.

   `$post = $request->all();
   if (\Auth::attempt(['email' => $post['email'], 'password'=>$post['password']]))
      return 'loginSuccess';
   return 'loginFailed';`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to encrypt/decrypt the password, Laravel doing it by itself. You just need to pass the plain password. look below

```
$post = $request->all();

if (\Auth::attempt(['email' => $post['email'], 'password' => '1234dfgG')]))
    return 'loginSuccess';
return 'loginFailed';
```

While attempting, Laravel will apply its own `bcrypt` method for encryption and matching the password